# how to convert localdatetime into GMT?

Tags: java, datetime

i have string date like this

```
2020-05-19 10:46:09 this is Asia/Jakarta time
```

i want to convert become GMT and here my code

```
String created = New_tradingHistory_trade.getCreated_at();
                    Date date1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(created);
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
                    sdf.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                    String CreatedGMT = sdf.format(date1);
                    System.out.print(CreatedGMT);
```

what i got always like
2020-05-19 10:46:09 2020-05-19 10:46:09 my question is how to convert my date to GMT ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should use the [java-8 date time api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) and stop using legacy [Date](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html) and [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)

1. The input string you have is in local date time
2. So parse it into [LocalDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDateTime.html) using [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html)
3. Then convert localDateTime into [ZoneDateTime](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html) at zone `Asia/Jakarta`
4. Finally convert zoneDateTime into `GTM` date time which is equal to `UTC`

---

```
String input = "2020-05-19 10:46:09";

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(input,formatter);

ZonedDateTime zoneDateTime = localDateTime.atZone(ZoneId.of("Asia/Jakarta"));

System.out.println(zoneDateTime);

ZonedDateTime gmtDateTime = zoneDateTime.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC);

System.out.println(gmtDateTime);
```